# Android Room : Issue with 'no such table'

Tags: android, android-room

I've got a strange issue with with android room. To me its pretty confusing, so its hard to describe.
Basically I have 3 different Activities called Dasbboard, Horse and Breed.
Within the Dasboard one can start either the Horse or Breed activity. Depending if I made a query to one of either table in the Dashboard activity, opening the other activity crashes with message that no such table exists.

Here a snippet from DashboardActivity where I commented a query to a table. model.getHorseCount() is commented. And if I start the app now and try opening the Horse Activity, the app crashes. Same goes for the model.getBreed() line.

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        DashboardViewModel model = (DashboardViewModel) ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DashboardViewModel.class);

        TextView tvHorses = findViewById(R.id.textViewHorsesCount);
        TextView tvBreeds = findViewById(R.id.textViewClientsCount);

//        model.getHorseCount().observe( this, count -> tvHorses.setText(String.valueOf(count)));
        model.getBreedCount().observe( this, count -> tvBreeds.setText(String.valueOf(count)));

    }
```

Following the stacktrace:

```
2019-01-22 19:40:51.500 31771-31789/ch.labrat.roomtester E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: horse
2019-01-22 19:40:51.501 31771-31789/ch.labrat.roomtester E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: arch_disk_io_0
    Process: ch.labrat.roomtester, PID: 31771
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: horse (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * from horse ORDER BY name ASC
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1408)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1383)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.query(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:161)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:238)
        at ch.labrat.roomtester.features.horse.HorseDao_Impl$5.compute(HorseDao_Impl.java:288)
        at ch.labrat.roomtester.features.horse.HorseDao_Impl$5.compute(HorseDao_Impl.java:274)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ComputableLiveData$2.run(ComputableLiveData.java:101)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I dont know how much sense it makes to put here a lot of code fragments. If it helps, I sure will do. But I think best is to get my code from github and see yourself.

You can get it here: https://github.com/Nexotap/Roomtester

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Is "breed" working?

Comment: where's your `horse`?

Comment: Breed and horse are working. You can find them in the github.

Comment: Its really difficult to explain, since I have the feeling somethimes its working and sometimes not. The last what I've tried is to comment either one of those lines in Dashboard activity, which makes it working. But even then, sometimes I get the error of not having a such table. Maybe it's a timing problem? Best is to try it out yourself.

Comment: While reading through many posts in different places, I found a possible workaround.
Someone mentioned to disable WAL. for the database. So I tried that:

Room.databaseBuilder(...).setJournalMode(JournalMode.TRUNCATE)


Somehow it works now. But I have no clue what that really means and if it really solves the problem.

Comment: I think you have not pushed all the necessary files to github repo. Project level gradle file was missing, app folder was missing. Overall, the project failed to build.

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry. I don't use git a lot and it seems I've used a wrong root. Unfortunately I have no access to my computer for the next 10 days. Unless someone can help with only the source files, I'll upload the whole project when I'm back home.

Comment: Ok, I have now reuploaded the whole project. It should run now as expected as long as the WAL is disabled. Which means, when you comment line 35 in following file: https://github.com/Nexotap/Roomtester/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ch/labrat/roomtester/database/AnimaRoomDatabase.java behaves as I explained already. Maybe you can have a look now? Or someone else?

Comment: Very interesting. Seems I'm the only one on this world, having this problem?